# How to get if the data is same in mysql?

Tags: mysql

i have a query:

```sql
select `pcd`.`amount`, `pcd`.`payment_channel_id`, `pcd`.`reload_uc_id`, `pcd`.`is_vip`, `c`.`currency_code` as `currency` 
from `payment_channel_denominations` as `pcd` 
inner join `unipin_reload_denominations` as `urd` on `urd`.`id` = `pcd`.`reload_uc_id` 
left join `countries` as `c` on `c`.`id` = `urd`.`country_id` 
where `pcd`.`reload_uc_id` is not null 
and `urd`.`country_id` = 1 
and `pcd`.`amount` <> 'urd.credits'
```

| amount | payment_channel_id | reload_uc_id | is_vip | currency |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 3500.00 | 50 | 1 | 1 | IDR |
| 3800.00 | 50 | 1 | 0 | IDR |
| 1000.00 | 58 | 5 | 0 | IDR |
| 1000.00 | 50 | 5 | 0 | IDR |
| 100000.00 | 50 | 6 | 0 | IDR |

how to get only rows is_vip=1, if payment_channel_id dan reload_uc_id is same value?
i want to the result like this:

| amount | payment_channel_id | reload_uc_id | is_vip | currency |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 3500.00 | 50 | 1 | 1 | IDR |
| 1000.00 | 58 | 5 | 0 | IDR |
| 1000.00 | 50 | 5 | 0 | IDR |
| 100000.00 | 50 | 6 | 0 | IDR |

Answer (score 0):

```sql
WITH cte AS (

select `pcd`.`amount`, 
       `pcd`.`payment_channel_id`, 
       `pcd`.`reload_uc_id`, 
       `pcd`.`is_vip`, 
       `c`.`currency_code` as `currency`,
       ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY `pcd`.`payment_channel_id`, `pcd`.`reload_uc_id`
                          ORDER BY `pcd`.`is_vip` DESC) rn
from `payment_channel_denominations` as `pcd` 
inner join `unipin_reload_denominations` as `urd` on `urd`.`id` = `pcd`.`reload_uc_id` 
left join `countries` as `c` on `c`.`id` = `urd`.`country_id` 
where `pcd`.`reload_uc_id` is not null 
  and `urd`.`country_id` = 1 
  and `pcd`.`amount` <> 'urd.credits'
 
)

SELECT amount, payment_channel_id, reload_uc_id, is_vip, currency
FROM cte
WHERE rn = 1;
```

PS. Initial query text is copied as-is. Despite the fact that last condition seems to be wrong.